# Brownian motion integral variation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $h:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function.

Show that $I_t:=\int_0^t h'(u)B_u du$ has finite variation, where $B_u$ is Brownian motion.

To prove:

$\sup_{N\in \mathbb N} \left\{\sum_{k=1}^N|I_{t_k}-I_{t_{k-1}}|,a\le t_1<\dots<t_N\le b \right\}<\infty$.

Every estimation i take leads to the variation of Brownian motion which is infinite. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $I_t$ is $C^1$, and every $C^1$ function has locally finite variation.  If you want it to have finite variation over all of $[0,\infty)$, I don't think that is true.

Comment: Is there a proof that every $C^1$ function has locally finite variation?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is $C^1$ on an interval $[a,b]$; then $|f'|$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ by some constant, call it $M$.  Now for any $x,y$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \le M |x-y|$.  It follows that the variation of $f$ over $[a,b]$ is at most $M\cdot(b-a)$